# Customizing a Client-Side Form Validator in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, customization

Although I've never worked with symfony, I decided to make a big project my first adventure with symfony2 framework.

I created a signup/login system, But I encountered a small customization issue:

[image]

As you can see in the previous screenshot, there's a Symfony2 Default Client-Side Validator, and what I want is to customize it, changing its style, look, and translate its text in English (It's french in the screenshot BTW) using the translator object.

This is a portion of the form twig view:

```
<li>
   {{ form_errors(registerForm.password,{'attr':{'class' : 'err errx1'}}) }}
   {{ form_widget(registerForm.password,{'attr':{'class' : 'inpt mdx2','placeholder':'signup.password'| trans | capitalize}}) }}
        </li>
```

Is there any documentation providing a solution to this very issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you are seeing is the default HTML5 client validation.  This doesn't really have anything to do with Symfony, besides the fact that you can configure if you want it or not.  If you do not want this validation message to appear, you can add the following when you are rendering your form:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

The same goes for `form_row` if you want to disable it only for specific rows.

Take a look at [The docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-forms-html5-validation-disable) for more info.

If you want to customize your validation errors from the server, that's a bit more work.  I would submit the request viz ajax, and then use the response to apply my custom validation errors.  There are several ways to do it, just depends what you are comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering why I can't right-click on it to view it in firebug.

Actually, I've never worked with Html5 features this far...+1

Comment: So, I will remove these validators, then customize the server-side ones for my needs.

After all, I won't need client-side validations here.